# Can't start Ruby On Rails Webbrick server using Mysql2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webrick

I just started learning Ruby on Rails and i'm going through Lynda Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Training. So far everything was looking really good (no errors while installing everything), but when i tried to run Webbrick server i get error.
Can someone please help me to debug this server log.

I'm working on windows 8

ruby -v

```
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08) [x64-mingw32]
```

rails -v

```
Rails 4.1.5
```

gem --version mysql2

```
2.4.1
```

Because error is too big i'm giving you a link to txt file.

[Click here](http://pastebin.ca/2835141)

Comment: Does your MYSQL2 gem install correctly? I see you're using Windows

Comment: jep it was. 
First i had to copy/past libmysql.dll to Ruby directory. 
Then: gem install mysql2 (with added mysql lib and include directory)
installation was successful

Comment: Okay nice! I answered before seeing your comment. If you'd like me to delete my answer, please just say. I think you should try `bundle install`

Comment: I am having same issue with `sqlite3`, 'rails 4' and `ubuntu`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, you mention you're using `Windows`, and you're a newbie, so I'll give you some information on how to get the infamous `mysql2` gem working on your system (which is likely to be the problem):

---

**MYSQL2**

Because Windows does not come with many developer dependencies (including MYSQL), installing gems such as `mysql2`, `rmagick` and `curl` don't work out of the box

Instead, you have to first install the development dependencies (often referred to as ["header files"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive)) in order to install the gem. This is how you do it with MYSQL2 (by the way, we've [written a tutorial about this here](https://medium.com/p/installing-the-mysql2-rubyonrails-gem-on-windows-7-8-a028f44d87f3))

--

You need to ensure the MYSQL2 gem installs on your Windows system. This is done using 3 steps:

> 1. Install the [MYSQL C-Connector header files](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/)
> 2. Install the MYSQL2 gem, referencing the newly installed MYSQL C-Connector files
> 3. Copy libmysql.dll from your MYSQL folder to your Ruby folder

Firstly, you need to install the `mysql c-connector` header files:

[image]

Please note you must ALWAYS install the `32` bit version of the C-Connector library, regardless of which version of Windows you're using. Also, you need to **install to a file path which has no spaces**

Once you've done this, you then need to be able to install the `mysql2` gem, whilst referencing the newly installed MYSQL library:

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:\mysql-connector-path"'
```

This gives you the ability to install the gem by referencing the files it needs. That's why you need to install the dependencies without any spaces.

If this installs the gem, you then need to copy the `libmysql.dll` file:

[image]

---

Now this is just a presumption

You need to ensure you have the gem installed in order to get the server running.

Comment: I will tray again (fresh start)...
I will let you know if it works

Comment: i'm sorry. Stil facing the same problem

Comment: Hmm okay, can you tell us any other dependencies you have in your app?

Answer (score 1):

There is a patch for the related issue: https://copy.com/CHZ4eT4us6f1/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-winx64.zip where it's discussed in https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/372

You can download the file at the above [link](https://copy.com/CHZ4eT4us6f1/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-winx64.zip) and extract to the disk, assume you unzip to "D:" drive as `D:\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-winx64`

Try to install `mysql2` gem again.

`gem install mysql2 --no-rdoc --no-ri -- '--withmysql-dir="D:\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-winx64\bin" --with-mysql-lib="D:\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-winx64\lib" --with-mysql-include="D:\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-winx64\include"'`

Then, copy `libmysql.dll` file from `D:\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-winx64\lib` folder to `D:\Ruby\bin\` folder.

Finally, try to start rails webrick server again.

Comment: successfully installed gem, but problem is basicly the same...
When i run: rails server
http://pastebin.com/Yc3PrRAv

Comment: Do you mean you successfully installed gem with the patch and copied `libmysql.dll` to the proper place? If so, raise a new issue at https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues would also be helpful.

Comment: jep, everthing is in proper place. I will open new issue. Thx for effort!

Comment: maybe is not mysql2 gem issue...
I have created a new project (rails new testis) and when i try to run rails server i get this error
http://pastebin.com/3CbmRP3K

Comment: @DavorBramorPečnik I think this is a different issue, you might have to add `gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:x64_mingw,:mingw, :mswin]` line to your Gemfile and `bundle install` (or `bundle update`). But for mysql2 issue, I think you will face the same error again.

Comment: you were right! It is different issue, so im going to report bug on link you have provided.

Comment: @DavorBramorPečnik superb :)